# Visual studio Express 2012 running issues in Windows 8 Release preview for Windows Store Apps

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am using Windows 8 Release Preview 64 bit Operating system for my Visual Studio Express edition 2012 for Windows Store Development. But the XAML design page is not working. It is getting Error is

System.Exception
Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF3)

The alert box is showing as There are Deployment Errors
 When i try to execute any Project it is showing the displaying error is

The project "App1" needs to be deployed before it can be started.

Verify the project is sekected to be deployed in the Solution Configration Manager,
or deploy it explicitly by clicking one of the Deploy commands in the Build menu.

Then finally error is

Registration of the app failed.Windows cannit install package b048fc10-8037-494c-8b3f-0191a2c1bf33 becaus this package requires a higher Windws version. 
The package requestedWindws version. 
The package requested windws version 6.2 with AppModel verison ,While the current Windows version is 6.2 with AppModel verison 0.(0x80073cfd)

Can any one help me to debug the error.. It's important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are definitely going to run into issues running RTM software (VS) on the pre-release OS.  My best advice to you is to get the release version of Windows 8.

If that's not possible, you can open Package.Appxmanifest with the XML editor in visual studio.  In there you'll find a Prerequisites section containing the minimum and maximum OS version.  Change the values there to 6.1.0 (IIRC) and your app should run.

**WARNING** The behaviour of your app is not guaranteed though - changes in the OS between release candidate and RTM mean that some behvaviour has changed, and some may not be supported on the older version at all.  Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: Thank u for this Reply... Right now i am using Windows Release preview for VS2012 express edition for Store apps. Can i try any other Windows Operating Systems for Resolving this problem.

Comment: You should be running the release version of Windows.  You will find that there are large areas of the OS that have changed since release preview, and if you are developing against that version your apps will not be guaranteed to work on the final release.

Comment: Without this may i can install any other windows os for Store apps.

Comment: The point is that if you are developing for the store, your users will be running the release version of Windows 8, so you should be running that yourself to ensure compatibility.

Comment: Apart from this Can i Use the VS 2012 Express edition in Windows Release preview for learning purpose means try for what's new development for Windows Store Apps. With the changing value in minimum   & maximum both version(What you Said).. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As You said I changed the minimum & maximum OS version values in Package. Appxmanifest ., But there is no impact in Visual Studio. Reply me to convey this Error.

Comment: I really don't know what else to tell you.  You are running an unsupported (and unsupportable) combination of OS and Visual Studio.  Things will not work properly like that.  You need to upgrade to the release version of Windows.

Comment: I agree with you. There are many Versions of operating systems in Windows 8, Which one i prefer for Windows Store development. As i said earlier i need development for the purpose of learning only. I need  the Windows edition for free download.

Answer (score 0):

My wish is try for Enterprise edition.If you want to want the Windows 8 Enterprise edition you can download [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh699156.aspx?ocid=wc-tn-wctc)

When you choose any version it is asking for your Microsoft credentials.